# Inplace updating of function arguments

Tags: julia

I need an efficient implementation of the cartesian product for a variable number of arrays.

I have tried the `product` function from `Iterators.jl`, but the performance was lacking.

I am a python hacker and have used [this function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9e10ec017b15f7549ba462dcd5c2bf089bc318e4/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L493-L543) from sklearn and have had good performance results with it.

I have tried to write a Julia version of this function, but am not able to produce the same results as the python function.

My code is:

```
function my_repeat(a, n)
    # mimics numpy.repeat
    m = size(a, 1)
    out = Array(eltype(a), n * m)
    out[1:n] = a[1]
    for i=2:m
        out[(i-1)*n+1:i*n] = a[i]
    end
    return out
end

function cartesian(arrs; out=None)
    dtype = eltype(arrs[1])

    n = prod([size(i, 1) for i in arrs])

    if is(out, None)
        out = Array(dtype, n, length(arrs))
    end

    m = int(n / size(arrs[1], 1))
    out[:, 1] = my_repeat(arrs[1], m)

    if length(arrs[2:]) > 0
        cartesian(arrs[2:], out=out[1:m, 2:])
        for j = 1:size(arrs[1], 1)-1
            out[(j*m + 1):(j+1)*m, 2:] = out[1:m, 2:]
        end
    end

    return out
end
```

I test it with the following:

```
aa = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7])
cartesian(aa)
```

The return value is:

```
12x3 Array{Float64,2}:
1.0  9.88131e-324  2.13149e-314
1.0  2.76235e-318  2.13149e-314
1.0  9.88131e-324  2.13676e-314
1.0  9.88131e-324  2.13676e-314
2.0  9.88131e-324  2.13149e-314
2.0  2.76235e-318  2.13149e-314
2.0  9.88131e-324  2.13676e-314
2.0  9.88131e-324  2.13676e-314
3.0  9.88131e-324  2.13149e-314
3.0  2.76235e-318  2.13149e-314
3.0  9.88131e-324  2.13676e-314
3.0  9.88131e-324  2.13676e-314
```

I believe that the problem here is that when I use this line: `cartesian(arrs[2:], out=out[1:m, 2:])`, the keyword argument `out` is not updated inplace in the recursive calls.

As can be seen, I have done a very naive translation of the Python version of this function (see link from above). It might well be possible that there are internal language differences that make a naive translation impossible. I don't think this is true because of this quote from the [functions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#argument-passing-behavior) section of the julia documentation:

> Julia function arguments follow a convention sometimes called “pass-by-sharing”, which means that values are not copied when they are passed to functions. Function arguments themselves act as new variable bindings (new locations that can refer to values), but the values they refer to are identical to the passed values. Modifications to mutable values (such as Arrays) made within a function will be visible to the caller. This is the same behavior found in Scheme, most Lisps, Python, Ruby and Perl, among other dynamic languages.

How can I make this (or an equivalent) function work in Julia?

Comment: Because the type of `out` cannot be inferred by the compiler (it might be `None` or it might be an `Array`), you're going to have trouble with performance here no matter how you handle array-slicing. A better approach might be to avoid the keyword for the second argument (just change the semicolon into a comma) and initialize it as `Array(eltype(arrs[1]),  prod([size(i, 1) for i in arrs]), length(arrs))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

It it not an issue of Julia not updating function arguments in place, but instead a problem with the using slice operator `a[ind]`, which  makes a copy of the data, instead of indexing my array by reference. This part of the [multi dimensional array](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#implementation)  documentation held the answer:

> SubArray is a specialization of AbstractArray that performs indexing by reference rather than by copying. A SubArray is created with the sub function, which is called the same way as getindex (with an array and a series of index arguments). The result of sub looks the same as the result of getindex, except the data is left in place. sub stores the input index vectors in a SubArray object, which can later be used to index the original array indirectly.

The problem was fixed by changing this line from:

```
cartesian(arrs[2:], out=out[1:m, 2:])
```

to the following:

```
out_end = size(out, 2)
cartesian(arrs[2:], out=sub(out, 1:m, 2:out_end))
```

Comment: I think the slice operator will return a SubArray in future versions of Julia, but that will probably not break this code.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `repeat` function in Base.

A shorter and faster variant might use the `@forcartesian` macro in the Cartesian package:

```
using Cartesian

function cartprod(arrs, out=Array(eltype(arrs[1]), prod([length(a) for a in arrs]), length(arrs)))
    sz = Int[length(a) for a in arrs]
    narrs = length(arrs)
    @forcartesian I sz begin
        k = sub2ind(sz, I)
        for i = 1:narrs
            out[k,i] = arrs[i][I[i]]
        end
    end
    out
end
```

The order of rows is different than your solution, but perhaps that doesn't matter?

Comment: This works very well. Thanks for the answer. I just checked it out and the Cartesian package is pretty awesome (although I need to spend some time to wrap my head around how to use those macros)! Is it possible that `out[k,i] = arrs[i][I[i]]` could be further optimized so as not to do 4 slice operations in this inner-most loop? (this idea comes from my Python background where slicing is rather costly in tight inner loops)

Comment: FYI, for some very simple profiles like `cartesian([[1:j] for i=1:k])`, the performance of my function is between 1.1-1.5 times worse than the performance of this function, depending on the values of `i` and `j`. So this is an improvement!

Comment: Not as much of an improvement as I would have suspected, however. If you're using small arrays, it probably won't matter how you solve this.

Comment: If you're really performance-sensitive, then yes, you could arrange it so that the slicing is done once per item. Check out the `@nloops` macro, specifically in its `preexpr` form.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the answer has changed as Julia has progressed.

The basic problem is that slices like `a[1:3,:]` make a copy. If you update that copy in a function, it has no effect on `a` itself.

The modern answer is to use `@view a[1:3,:]` to get a reference to part of the underlying array. Updates to this view will be reflected in the underlying array.

You can force an entire block of code to use view-semantics with the `@views` macro.

See [Inplace updating of function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498323/inplace-updating-of-function-arguments) for more discussion.